# EF Core exception with ToDictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have this simple EF Core query which throws an exception, to my surprise:

```
var test = await _context.GroupMessages
    .Select(m => new MinimalChannelMessage()
    {
        id = m.Id,
        er = m.Emojis.ToDictionary(e => e.Emoji, e => e.Users.Select(u => u.UserId))
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

As you can see from the query, the tables are `GroupMessages -> Emojis -> N-to-M table with UserId`

The exception I get is:

> When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.

I haven't been able to figure out why this simple query fails, or what the exception message is trying to tell me. I'm happy for any help!

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18440) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the suggested bug report https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18440 might be related, I had trouble finding an alternative amongst those listed. I tried...

`er = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(m.Emojis.AsEnumerable().Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(e.Emoji, e.Users.Select(u => u.UserId).ToArray())))`

`er = m.Emojis.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(e => e.Emoji, e => e.Users.Select(u => u.UserId).ToArray())`

None of those two worked for me. So I ultimately had to just include the whole tree, then do the ToDictionary in memory...

Comment: Cold comfort, there has never been an EF version supporting this.